# Is it safe to implement business logic inside a catch block?

Tags: android

I want to update a shared preference and ImageView(using setImageResource) inside a catch block. But is is safe to do so?

```
try{
  //do something
} catch (Exception e) [
  Log.d("TAG", "Exception " + e);
  sharedPref.edit().putString("Value", "no_value").apply();
  myimageview.setImageResource(resid);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok to do that. Actually there is no another way to execute code when some exception happen. Of course it is better if you know the type of exception (for example null pointer) and to use something like:

```
if(something != null){
// normal logic
}else{
// exception logic
}
```

Comment: Will take it as the answer :)